# php check if date is today or greater. but only in this month

Tags: php, date, if-statement, time, strtotime

I have a list of dates and need to enforce a limit, which is the list to not be older than today but more than 30 days ahead of today.

Is possible to modify what I have or do I need to use something like 'time' instead? if so how would I adjust what I have?

```
$date = new DateTime($page->meta_value);

if (strtotime($page->meta_value) > time()) {
    echo '<h2><div class="date-title">';
    echo $page->post_title.' - ';
    echo '</div><div class="date-date">';
    echo $date->format('d-m-Y').'<br/>';
    echo '</div></h2>';
}
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: A combination of `date()`  `strtotime()` and other time function will help you. Read about the format in `date()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php the rest is simple math.

Comment: thanks @JustOnUnderMillions - which other time function do you mean?

Comment: tangent...but also have a look at the Carbon library.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php + brain = solution. Tip `date('N')` for example gives the day of the week (1-6).

Comment: Thanks for your help guys but I ended up using @nggit solution with a little tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (strtotime($page->meta_value) >= time() && strtotime($page->meta_value) < strtotime('+30 days')) {
```

Or up to this month only?

```
if (strtotime($page->meta_value) >= time() && strtotime($page->meta_value) < strtotime('first day of next month')) {
```

Comment: thanks @nggit this did the trick, I ended up creating a few more date ranges too!!

Answer (score 1):

Things that can help you:

`print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last day of this month'));`

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

`print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+ 30 days'));`

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

Read more here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php